# SpliteViewController setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _masterColumnWidth in iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, ios10, xcode8

I have upgraded application to `iOS 10` and `XCode 8`, after upgrading application is crashing in iPad with log as follows:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key _masterColumnWidth.'

Check full crash log below:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key _masterColumnWidth.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bdc634b **exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010b32b21e objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010bdc6299 -[NSException raise] + 9   3   Foundation
>
>   0x0000000106ace2ff -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] +
>   291   4   UIKit                               0x000000010803c8c3
>   -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88     5   Profiler                            0x0000000104319ae5 -[AppDelegate
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 3765    6   UIKit
>
>   0x0000000107e9968e -[UIApplication
>   _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 290  7   UIKit                               0x0000000107e9b013
>   -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4236   8   UIKit                               0x0000000107ea13b9 -[UIApplication
>   _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731   9   UIKit                               0x0000000107e9e539 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
>     10  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001110ff76b
>   __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24     11  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001110ff5e4
>   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189  12  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001110ff96d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] +
>   45    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd6b311
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd5059c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556   15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd4fa86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918     16  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010bd4f494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420     17  UIKit
>   0x0000000107e9cdb6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434    18  UIKit
>   0x0000000107ea2f34 UIApplicationMain + 159    19  Profiler
>   0x000000010458fb9f main + 111     20  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010cfa968d start + 1  21  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 )

Used below code to set `masterColumnWidth` of `SpliteViewController`:

```
SpliteViewController *objSpliteViewController = [[Navigation getStoryBord] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SpliteViewController"];

[objSpliteViewController setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:370.0f] forKey:@"_masterColumnWidth"];
```

Works fine in iOS version below 10 and XCode version below 8.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 10 access to this internal property is not possible. Generally speaking, accessing these kind of properties is a risky practice. You should use either appropriate properties or methods to modify the master column's width:

**1. Properties**

```
objSpliteViewController.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 370.0;
objSpliteViewController.minimumPrimaryColumnWidth = 370.0;
```

**2. Methods**

```
[objSpliteViewController setMaximumPrimaryColumnWidth:370.0];
[objSpliteViewController setMinimumPrimaryColumnWidth:370.0];
```

Set both(maximum and minimum) to achieve exact width or just one of them to prevent column from getting too wide or too narrow.